# Can't create a config to connect to aws EC2 over ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

If I connect like that:

```
ssh -i "aws.pem" ubuntu@ec2-*-***-***-**.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Everything works fine, but if I try to set up a config for that:

```
Host sserv
        Hostname ec2-*-***-***-**.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
        User ubuntu
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aws.pem
```

I can't connect...

Here's what I get when I run `ssh -v sserv`:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/mrlalatg/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/mrlalatg/.ssh/config line 20: Applying options for sserv
debug1: /home/mrlalatg/.ssh/config line 30: Applying options for sserv
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to *.*.*.* [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: connect to address *.*.*.* port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host *.*.*.* port 22: Connection timed out
```

Also tried it with sudo:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname sserv: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

ADDITION: Screenshot of a successful connection without config
[image: screenshot of a successful connection]

NOTE: All sensitive information is covered with *

Comment: ssh file looks fine. Are you sure you are using same host and that manuall ssh command works?

Comment: @Marcin I am sure, I copypasted it several times...

Comment: @Marcin Added a screenshot of a successful connection

Comment: The ssh config file looks fine. It is what I also use. Don't see why you would time out based on it.

Comment: @Marcin Which rights do aws.pem file should have? I used `chmod 400` on it because that's what aws suggests. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: 400 is fine. You would get different error if the issue was the ssh key.

Comment: Do you have any other server/instance running with ssh config setup? Just wonder if this is only this one instance issue, or general ssh config problem?

Comment: @Marcin this is the only one ssh connection to aws, I have other connections configured for my work, they work fine (they are not hosted on any cloud, just a machine in our office), also some time ago I was connecting to another vds (not by aws) and everything was working just fine…

Comment: @Marcin Maybe it's because I have a Basic plan or sth?

Comment: Its some connection issue. But I don't know why manual ssh would work, while ssh through config wouldn't.

Comment: When it says `Connecting to *.*.*.* [*.*.*.*]`, does the IP address displayed match the IP address of the instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It doesn't match!

Comment: @Marcin as you were interested in this question.

The problem was me, I am a dumb potato because I didn't notice a config entry with the same name higher than this one, so it was trying to connect to my old server

Comment: @Marcin What should I do with this question, can I somehow delete it because it's just my fault. I am really sorry for wasting your time..

Comment: @MrLalatg You can answer your own question if you find what's happening. But John was spot on, so you can accept his.

Answer (score 2):

> connect to host *.*.*.* port 22: Connection timed out

As per above line, this looks like a **security group issue**. Mostly timeout issue is related to security groups. Please check your security group and **make sure you have enabled port 22 for your IP**. If your IP is dynamic then please check **current IP and security group IP**.

Also check `aws.pem` file permission.

Comment: The OP wrote that it all works without the config file. If it didn't, he wouldn't be able to connect either way.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the IP address displayed in the debug log does not match the IP address assigned to the instance.

Amazon EC2 instances can change IP address when they are stopped and started. To avoid this from happening, you can assign an Elastic IP address to the instance, which will then maintain the same IP address.

It is possible that the instance received a new IP address, but you have not updated the entry in the `config` file, so **it is still trying to connect to an old IP address**. You should update the host name in the config file.

Comment: When you run the SSH command, is the debugging show the correct IP address? If not, I suggest you change the config file to use the IP address rather than the DNS name. If it is showing the wrong IP address, then you will need to track-down where it is coming from.

Comment: I already changed the config file so now it had the elastic ip

Comment: And what is showing in the debug log? Is it using the Elastic IP address?

Comment: Ok I got it, the thing is I am a dumb potato, I have a config entry with the same name higher than this one. 
I am really sorry for wasting your time..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it and I feel dumb for wasting other people's time.

The problem was that I had another ssh config entry with the same name higher than this one, so I was actually connecting to my old server (which is not working anymore). And I got a timeout error